# Algorithm that mix array respecting certain constraints

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I've this problem:

i must develop an algorithm that get an int array and reshuffles the elements respecting these constraints:

For each  element, must be lower than its neighbors or greater than its neighbors:

```
for each x in array a,
( a[x-1]<=a[x] AND a[x+1]<=a[x] )
OR
( a[x-1]>=a[x] AND a[x+1]>=a[x] )
```

This all in theta(n log n) in the worst case

I've no idea how to do this, my only intuition is that i must do something similar to merge-sort...

Sorry for mi poor English

Comment: Maybe I've found a solution, I could sort the array than get alternately the first and last element  
  
I think it's a good idea...

Answer (score 4):

1. Sort the array
2. Cut it in halfs
3. Put elements from first half in between elements of the second half
4. If number of elemnts is not even move last element to the front

Example:

1. `2 3 1 5 7 8 6 4 9`
2. `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
3. `1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8 9`
4. `9 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8`

Comment: Should also work and would be easier than my answer; could there be some corner cases however?

Comment: Yes for example if number of elements is odd.

Comment: @piotrekg12 That's what I forgot too - move the last group to the front.

Answer (score 0):

As a naive approach, you could perform some sorting first and group the array to groups of equal size. Afterwards, adjacent groups would have to be pairwise switched; if the number of groups is odd, the first group needs to be switched to the back.

An example:

Input: `9 9 8 8 7 7 6 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1` (already sorted)

Groups: `(9 9) (8 8) (7 7) (6 6) (5 5) (4 4) (3 3) (2 2) (1 1)`

Groups pairwise switched: `(8 8) (9 9) (6 6) (7 7) (4 4) (5 5) (2 2) (3 3) (1 1)`

First group moved to the back: `(9 9) (6 6) (7 7) (4 4) (5 5) (2 2) (3 3) (1 1) (8 8)`

Perhaps the idea can be refined to obtain a better algorithm.

Comment: Yes, but what if I've not all pairs?  
I could have an array similar this:
2 3 1 5 7 8 6 4 9

Comment: Sorting yields `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`, grouping yields `(9) (8) (7) (6) (5) (4) (3) (2) (1)`, switching yields `(8) (9) (6) (7) (4) (5) (3) (2) (1)`.

Comment: Switching first element to the back yields `(9) (6) (7) (4) (5) (3) (2) (1) (8)`.